# Does "I walked all the way to school" refer to a continuous movement without stops on the way to school?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Suppose my school is about 2 kilometers from my house.

I was walking to school but I stopped to talk with many people several times on the way.

That was not a continuous journey, but a broken journey.

The journey was interrupted by many stops, but **I still made it to school**.

Can we still use "**all the way**" in that situation?

Does "**I walked all the way to school**" refer to a continuous movement without stops on the way to school?

Answer (score 4):

**All the way** here means that you covered the whole journey on foot. It says nothing about whether or not you made any stops on the way.

Answer (score 0):

No, the expression is valid whether you so or not. But if the trip took a few days, say, I would expect the speaker to elaborate on why a short trip took a long time.